# fitting absolute div popup in screen

Tags: javascript, css, positioning

Sorry maybe I was not clear in my original question below...

What I am looking for is a way to get a popup to move inside the windows viewable area (not actually create the popup itself). As seen in Google image's when you mouseover a image at the edge of the screen, somehow (which is what I want to know), the script detects that there is not enough space for the popup to appear in the window, so it pushes it inside the viewable range.

So I want to know how this is determined and calculated.

> How can I use javascript to make sure
>   a popup div fits inside the window
>   when it appears?
>
> A good example is google's image
>   search. When a image does not fit in
>   the window (either it is the far right
>   most or bottom most image), somehow it
>   is pushed inside when the popup is
>   opened with the mouseover event. How
>   is this calculated and how can I
>   create a script to calculate this.

Comment: every modal script i have seen would take care of this for you

Comment: To all answers, I think his question wasn't very clear in that he's not talking about a modal window, rather his Google Image example is referring to the results page when you hover over a result near the edge of the screen and the result corrects itself so it's all in view.

Comment: Yes Marcel that is what I mean

Answer (score 0):

you can use already build pop-up box/overlay window js library. Use jQuery js framework and go for any plug-in that provide you the same feature. I recommend you to use facybox http://fancybox.net/ with jQuery which makes this very easy.

Answer (score 0):

There's no "use this code in your JS file" fix for this but the general idea is to reposition  and override the offsets of the element in question, taking into account the viewport's bounds (to state the obvious).

For example, a couple of good tooltip plugins for jQuery support this behaviour, such as bassistance's [jQuery Tooltip Plugin](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-tooltip/) and also [qTip](http://craigsworks.com/projects/qtip/docs/reference/#position-adjust-screen). It might be worth digging into their source and seeing how they handle this.

Comment: Hey both of those don't really do what I want. I already have a popup opening on mouseover, the problem is that when I mouseover it at the edge of the screen it makes the browsers create scroll bars to fit it in the screen. I want the popup itself to be pushed inside the browser

Comment: @alex: They both push their "pop-ups" back into the view port but it's a small part of their code. For example, for qTip I linked to the option for toggling the setting and in jQuery Tooltip, and a search for "viewport()" in the [jQuery Tooltip Plugin](http://jquery.bassistance.de/tooltip/jquery.tooltip.js) shows how that plugin handles this behaviour.

Comment: Do you know the raw javascript equivalents for: `x: $(window).scrollLeft(),
   y: $(window).scrollTop(),
   cx: $(window).width(),
   cy: $(window).height()
`

Answer (score -1):

This is one of the best i've come across http://gettopup.com/